# How to write a function from scratch to simulate a cellular automaton

Tags: cellular-automata

I would like to simulate a simple cellular automaton like [this](https://www.wolframscience.com/nks/p24--how-do-simple-programs-behave/) (rule 254), how do you do it from scratch in Mathematica without relying on the high-level function `CellularAutomaton`, which hides all the implementation details?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rule 254 is just a `BitOr` (or BitNor if you flip the colours and padding to 1) performed on a 3-element sliding window:

```
state0 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
update[state_] := MovingMap[BitOr @@ # &, state, {3, Center}, 0]
ArrayPlot[
 NestList[update, state0, 5]
]
```

[image: 254]

For general 3-valued boolean functions you can do this:

```
rule = 254;
state0 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

update[state_] := MovingMap[Boole[BooleanFunction[rule, 3]@@#] &,state,{3,Center},0]

ArrayPlot[
 NestList[update, state0, 5]
]
```

Comment: +1 for using `MovingMap`

Comment: How to specify your own boolean function? Without BooleanFunction for general case.

Comment: I did that in the BitOr case. There's also BitNor, BitXor, BitAnd etc. For anything else just write a function that takes three arguments and returns True or False.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a very simple implementation. It is not the fastest implementation but it probably works in Mathematica versions dating back to the 90s*.

```
rules[wcode_] := Thread@Rule[
   ReverseSortBy[Tuples[{1, 0}, 3], FromDigits[#, 2] &],
   PadLeft[IntegerDigits[wcode, 2], 8]
   ]

state = CenterArray[13];
step[wcode_][state_] := ArrayPad[Partition[state, 3, 1] /. rules[wcode], 1]
NestList[step[254], state, 5] // ArrayPlot
```

[image: Output]

```
NestList[step[30], state, 5] // ArrayPlot
```

[image: Output]

If you want to simulate more steps, make sure to increase the number 13 in `CenterArray` so that it corresponds to the width of the picture that you would like generate.

* `CenterArray` and `ArrayPad` are comparatively modern conveniences, but `Partition` existed in Mathematica 1.0 in 1988, and `FromDigits` and `IntegerDigits` existed in Mathematica 3.0 in 1996. In fact, Richard Gaylord's 1996 book [Modeling Nature: Cellular Automata Simulations with Mathematica](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387946209) uses `Partition` to implement a function for simulating cellular automata. (The technique can be easily extended to 2D as well.)

## Notes on Wolfram code

The implementation of [Wolfram codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_code) to evolution rules conversion can be explained as follows.

Each cellular automata consists of eight rules:

```
RulePlot[CellularAutomaton[254]]
```

[image: Output]

In this picture, black corresponds to 1 and white to 0. Consequently, these cells can be read out as `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}`. Converting this to a decimal yields the rule number:

```
FromDigits[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, 2]
```

> 254

Note that the cells have to be sorted in a particular way to get the right binary sequence.

The top row in each cell can be interpreted as a binary number. `{1, 1, 1}`, `{1, 1, 0}`, `{1, 0, 1}` etc. Each cell has a corresponding decimal number:

```
FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}
```

> {7, 6, 5}

The cells are sorted by their decimal numbers in descending order.

To convert from a Wolfram code to rules, we simply need to take these steps in reverse. We generate all possible cells, sort them by their decimal representation, and assign to each cell an output given by the binary representation of the rule number.

Some rules, such as rule 30, do not have a binary representation with eight digits.

```
IntegerDigits[30, 2]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}

i.e. there is not one number for each cell. In these cases we pad the binary representation with zeros on the left.

Comment: +1 for extended explanation.